# Merge two sorted results with intermittently of one on two

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Which way can I to use for merge two sorted result.

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS X(a);
┌───┐
│ a │
├───┤
│ 1 │
│ 2 │
│ 3 │
│ 4 │
└───┘
(4 rows)
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')) AS X(a);
┌───┐
│ a │
├───┤
│ A │
│ B │
│ C │
│ D │
└───┘
(4 rows)
```

And the result

```
┌───┐
│ a │
├───┤
│ A │
│ 1 │
│ B │
│ 2 │
│ C │
│ 3 │
│ D │
│ 4 │
└───┘
(4 rows)
```

I try some solution creating a new temporary column with modulo for each result but I block for the merge and I am not sure is really performing.

Thanks you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0c2503cfae47855363188ea15d7b44cf)

```
select a from (
    SELECT a::text, row_number() OVER() as rowcount, 2 as sort_table 
    FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS X(a)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a::text, row_number() OVER(), 1 
    FROM (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')) AS X(a)
) s

ORDER BY 
    rowcount, sort_table
```

You have to add some metadata to find the right sort order. First I added the `row_number()` window function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to both tables. This adds a unique row number per row. So this works as first order column. Now I am able to order by row number: First come the first rows of all tables followed by the second rows of the tables, ... Now you have two "first" rows in you result which have to be ordered. If you want the rows of the second table you can achieve this by a constant value. I named it `sort_table`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can be done using ROW_NUMBER, but why do you need that?

```
select a
from 
 (
   SELECT a, 2 as flag, row_number() over (order by a) as rn 
   FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS X(a)
   union all
   SELECT a, 1 as flag, row_number() over (order by a) as rn
   FROM (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')) AS X(a)
 ) as dt
order by rn, flag
```

Of course you need matching datatypes in both Selects.

Answer (score -1):

with cte(a, RowsNumber) as (
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(120), a) [a], ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a) [RowsNumber] FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS X(a) union all 
SELECT a, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a) [RowsNumber] FROM (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D')) AS X(a)) Select a from cte order by RowsNumber